# Pop-Up window with message in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work in ASP.NET MVC application (razor) that uses Kendo UI. I should show a Report when the customer clicks on the button. But, the Report is not so quick, and I should show a message in the pop-up window for the client, something like this:'Report being generated - in a moment a new window will appear with results'. How to show the Pop-up window with the message? And where in the code?Please see the code that I use. The button is:

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Patient" id="hrefAllCheckedPatientsRep" style="display:none;" href="#" onclick="getAllChecked();">Generate Report</a>&nbsp;
```

This is the function getAllChecked() in JavaScript:

```
function getAllChecked() {
        $('#checkedMsgRep').text('');    

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PatientReport/ExportToPDF",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { uniqueIds: checkedArray },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    // $('#lnkPdfDownload').show();
                    //$('#lnkPdfDownload').attr('href', '/PatientReport/DownloadFile' + '?fName=' + data.fName);
                    $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/PatientReport/DownloadFile' + '?fName=' + data.fName);
                } else {
                    //$('#lnkPdfDownload').hide();
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#checkedMsgRep').text('@ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Patient.PatientStrings.CheckedError').show();
                $('#hrefCheckedPatientsRep').blur();
            }
        });
        }
```

In the Controller I have an Action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            public ActionResult ExportToPDF(List<String> uniqueIds) {  
             // step 1: creation of a document-object
                var document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 3, 3, 80, 50);
//Here is the code for export to pdf
// Add table to the document
            document.Add(dataTable);

            //This is important don't forget to close the document
            document.Close();

        byte[] byteInfo = output.ToArray();
        output.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        output.Position = 0;          


        var fName = string.Format("File-{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
        Session[fName] = output;

        return Json(new { success = true, fName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

etc.

The other Action in Contoller is:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fName)
        {
            var ms = Session[fName] as MemoryStream;
            if (ms == null)
                return new EmptyResult();
            Session[fName] = null;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", fName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to create a div with message.

```
<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">    
<p>Loading Files...</p>
</div>
```

Use show function to display the popup inside your javascript function.

```
function getAllChecked() {$( "#effect" ).show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );}
```

And inside the ajax success hide the popup.

```
success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {$( "#effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of using popup, Why don't you use a loading gif image, which you can easily show and hide. You can show the image on generate report button click and hide inside ajax success using simple jQuery.